# Is there a community chat room?

Tags: support, faq, chat

Is there any way to chat with moderators or other members of the community?

Comment: I'm taking the `[featured]` tag off this because the chat links are now quite prominently displayed in a few different places on the main page.  Thought it was time for some cleanup. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. Join [The Frying Pan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan) today!

All are welcome to stop by.

Comment: I don't have the necessary rep to edit this, but note that this has now been migrated to chat.SE

Answer (score 1):

cooking.stackexchange now has a chat home on [chat.stackexchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com/); the "chat" option is now at the top of every Q&A page.

You aren't limited to 1 room - feel free to use chat for all (sensible) cooking chat-related purposes.